# SQLite database working on my emulator and doesn't work with my device

Tags: android

I'm working on an android application where I import my sqlite database into the android project .. the database works fine on the emulator but when i try the app on my device it doesn't work
and outputs a message : Unfortunately, appname has stopped.

I put my database in the assets folder in my project then use this code to copy it :

```
try {           
    String destPath = "/data/data/" + getPackageName() + "/databases/MyDB";
    File f = new File(destPath);            
    if (!f.exists()) {          
        CopyDB( getBaseContext().getAssets().open("mydb"), 
                new FileOutputStream(destPath));
    }
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {         
    e.printStackTrace();

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

copyDB function :

```
public void CopyDB(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) 
    throws IOException {
    //---copy 1K bytes at a time---
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        outputStream.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    inputStream.close();
    outputStream.close();
}
```

DBAdapter Class :

```
public class DBAdapter {
public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_NAME = "username";
public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";


private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "users";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;



private final Context context;    

private DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

public DBAdapter(Context ctx) 
{
    this.context = ctx;
    DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper 
{
    DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
    {

    }
}    

//---opens the database---
public DBAdapter open() throws SQLException 
{
    db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

//---closes the database---    
public void close() 
{
    DBHelper.close();
}


//---retrieves all the users---
public Cursor getAllusers() 
{
    return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
            KEY_PASSWORD}, null, null, null, null, null);
}

//---retrieves a particular user---
public User getuser(String username) throws SQLException 
{

    Cursor mCursor =
            db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PASSWORD}, KEY_NAME + "=" + "'"+username+ "'", null,
            null, null, null, null);
    if(mCursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
        User u=new User(Integer.valueOf(mCursor.getString(0)),mCursor.getString(1),mCursor.getString(2));
        return u;
    }else
        return null;

}
```

}

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Post the logcat showing the error.

Comment: how to check logcat while running the app on the device ?

Comment: I tried running the app on emulator with newer version of android ( android 4 ) just like my mobile .. it is now not working on the new emulator !

Answer (score 0):

Importing `SQLite` databases is basically a bad idea. You should be better off creating the Database from `raw xml`. This [tutorial](http://coenraets.org/blog/android-samples/androidtutorial/) should help. As for the question you can probably fix it by just clearing data of/ uninstalling the application.

Comment: I uninstalled the application and then re-installed it but nothing changed ... I need to have a database within my application

Comment: I tried running the app on emulator with newer version of android ( android 4 ) just like my mobile .. it is now not working on the new emulator !

Comment: @MustafaAbdel-Khalik Okay, please post the full logcat (select each logcat line and copy them using crtl+C) instead of screenshot.

Comment: Check if your sqlite db has a valid android structure (http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/). Verify if the table users is actually present. Also you can use pastebin.com instead of mediafire.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your LogCat it's difficult to guess what the error might be.

Looking at an app where I do the same thing, the only differences I see are in the copy function, and involve the order of operations and an additional method.

Try this in your CopyDB method at the end:

```
outputStream.flush(); 
outputStream.close(); 
inputStream.close();
```

Comment: I tried the app on newer emulator (android 4) with the same version of my device .. now it is not working on both the emulator and the device logcat : 
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/9/logcatt.png/

Comment: The logcat says it can't find a table, not the database.  Are you sure your db has a table called "users"?

Comment: yes sure ... it is working on emulator with android 2.1 but when i try on my phone (ice cream sandwich) or an emulator with android 4 it gives this error